# Shadow_dom in Selenium

Tags: dom, shadow

I started learning Selenium with Java online (Self study).I am struggling with targeting locators present under Shadow Dom. Could you please help me out with this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zGye.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gIzt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZGcP.png)

Thanks!

I tried JS querySelector and it takes me to the right path. However, Selenium thorugh an exception when I use CSS selector, ID etc.

```
document.querySelector('#react-root').querySelector('.StyledToolbar-sc-1gzot4c-0').querySelector('vwc-tab-bar')
```